# Putting and Eclipse installation into version control: Which files/folder should I ignore?

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, eclipse-plugin

I have the eclipse folder which i have all my plugins , workspace , etc stuff. Now i have put that in version control so that I have the copy of my working eclipse available on internet

Now the problem is when i use `git status` there are always few files like `.instance` which either keep changing or deleting . Maybe they're temp files.

So I want to know  what are those files which I can ignore so that I don't track them

The issue I have to put all eclipse is git is that when even I need to install eclipse in new VM or elsewhere then there is always some dependcy which is not downloable from internet and it cause all the plugins to stop.

So I thought as backup I always have something to work if new installation does not work

Comment: Do you want to put under `git` a project created with Eclipse or the Eclipse working dir?

Comment: @Atropo no , the whole eclipse folder. i dont have any projects . i usually have all projects in RSE . i only use eclipse as editor

Comment: @madhead - The OP is talking about putting eclipse itself under git the answer you are pointing to is about putting a project that uses eclipse under VCS.

Comment: It seems, sharing an Eclipse installation between different computers is no easily possible. See here: [How to keep an Eclipse installation in sync between multiple platforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176602/how-to-keep-an-eclipse-installation-in-sync-between-multiple-platforms-with-drop)